# Find the Intervals of Increase or Decrease, the concavity, and point of inflection for: $f(x)=(1-x)e^{-x}$

Tags: calculus

$$\begin{aligned}f(x)&=(1-x)e^{-x}\\
&=\frac{1-x}{e^{x}}\end{aligned}$$

Quotient Rule:

$$\begin{aligned}
f'(x) &=  e^x\cdot[1-x]'-(1-x)\cdot[e^x]' \\
&=e^x(-2+x)
\end{aligned}$$

What do I do now? Take the derivative again?

Comment: Whats with the down vote. And explanation would be nice. I don't see anything wrong with this question.

Comment: While I do not know the reason for the downvote, you forgot to divide by the square of the denominator when you took the derivative.  Remember that the quotient rule states that $$\left(\frac{f}{g}\right)' = \frac{f'g - fg'}{g^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

This will only be a hint:

An interval of decrease means the function is decreasing. What does that mean about the derivative? Can you solve for $x$ when $f'(x) < 0$?

An interval of increase means the function is increasing. What does that mean about the derivative? Can you solve for $x$ when $f'(x) > 0$?

The concavity of the function at a point means that the change of the function at that point is either increasing or decreasing. This is therefore related to the 2nd derivative. Can you find when $f''(x) > 0$? How about when $f''(x) < 0$?

A point of inflection is the point (or points) at which the 1st derivative is no longer changing. That is, $f''(x) = 0$. Can you solve for $x$ in this case as well?

Notice how once you done all of these (admittedly tedious) calculations, you'll basically be able to plot the function even if you don't really know what the function actually looks like. Simply by considering the derivatives of the function and when they're 0, positive, or negative.

Comment: Side note: when you do the quotient rule, make sure that you also divide the whole thing by the bottom squared. Or in your case, divide by $e^{2x}$.